# Running simulations varying parameter values in deSolve

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out how to run simulations varying parameter values while using deSolve. I am very new to R and having difficulty troubleshooting the errors I'm getting. I created a very simple set of differential equations and am trying to run a for loop sampling from a uniform distribution of my parameters.

My Model:

```
sir <- function(time, state, parameters) {

with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {

dS <- -beta1 * (S * I)/N
dI <-  beta1 * (S * I)/N - gamma1 * I
dR <-                 gamma1 * I

return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
})
}
init       <- c(S = 99999, I = 1, R = 0)
```

Attempt at for loop:

```
outlist <- list()
plist <- cbind(beta1 = runif(30, min = .1, max  = .9),
           gamma1 = runif(30, min = .1, max = .9))
for(i in 1:nrow(plist))
outlist[[i]] <- ode(y = init, times = times, func = sir, parms = plist[i])
plot(out, outlist)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'beta1' not found

I greatly appreciate any help you can provide,

Comment: You are not showing all your code. You haven't assigned a value to parameter `beta1` in your function as the error message implies. You should insert a line as `beta1 <- parameter[1]` in the function before the `with`. Similar for `gamma1` and `N` . And where are objects `times` and `N`? And you need `{` and `}` around the body of the `for` loop. Also missing is `out`. And now I give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has all sorts of errors. Even more that I noted in my comments.
A very typical error in R code: you use `plist[i]` to use row `i` of `plist`. You should use `plist[i,]`.

Having a go at your stuff:

```
library(deSolve)

sir <- function(time, state, parameters) {

    beta1 <- parameters[1]
    gamma1 <- parameters[2]
    with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {

    dS <- -beta1 * (S * I)/N
    dI <-  beta1 * (S * I)/N - gamma1 * I
    dR <-                 gamma1 * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
    })
}

init <- c(S = 99999, I = 1, R = 0)
times <- seq(1,5,.5) # trial
N <- 10000000 # having a guess
outlist <- list()
plist <- cbind(beta1 = runif(30, min = .1, max  = .9),
           gamma1 = runif(30, min = .1, max = .9))

plist[c(1,2)]
for(i in 1:nrow(plist)) {
    outlist[[i]] <- ode(y = init, times = times, func = sir, parms =  plist[i,])
}

# just display the first item
outlist[[1]]
```

It's up to you to assign to a variable `out` and to continue.